# Seek HTML Video with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm trying to seek to a specific part of a video, and I'd like to use JQuery.

`$('#video').currentTime` gives me undefined. Is there something I'm missing?

(`document.getElementById("video").currentTime` works)

Comment: `$('#video')[0].currentTime` or `$('#video').attr('currentTime')`?

Comment: `$("#video").attr("currentTime")` -?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's important to understand that jQuery selector functions return a jQuery object. As such, you cannot access properties directly unless jQuery has a special function set up to handle them.

What you want to do is fetch the `currentTime` property so you can use [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#video').prop('currentTime');
```

Or, if you're feeling more vanilla:

```
$('#video')[0].currentTime;
```

Comment: `var currentTime = $(obj).children("video").attr('currentTime');` I just get undefined but my obj is valid...

Comment: @Georodin Updated the answer to use prop(...) instead of attr(...). currentTime isn't an attribute on the element, it's a property on the js object. Give that a try instead!

Answer (score 0):

Note to set the time (seek), you should pass the value as the second parameter.

```
$('#video').attr('currentTime', 0);
```

Comment: The server also needs to include the following header in the response: "Accept-Ranges": "bytes"

Comment: this didn't work for me, using `prop()` instead of `attr()` made the trick